# Migrate local PostgreSQL to a AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is there a possibility how can I migrate my local PostgreDB to an AWS RDS Postgresql instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a `pg_dump` command on the command line to export your database, then import using the command line on an server than can connect to your RDS instance to import using either `pg_restore` or `psql`.

Amazon have additional details on how to do this via the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html).

**Alternatively** if AWS can communicate with your DB (either because it is public or you have established a VPN connection) you could use the [Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) to handle this process for you without you needing to run any of these commands.

Answer (score 0):

From server with IP allowed to access the RDS,

Import from local machine to RDS:

```
psql -h <host> -U <username> -p <port_no> -d <database_name> -f <database_file.sql>
```